# Sorting products by sale - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

I am using the following code in my function.php of my wordpress theme. And it sorts and display only the single products, not sorting/listing the variable products which are on discount/sale.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'wcs_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function wcs_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {

  $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'on_sale' == $orderby_value ) {

        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_sale_price';

    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'wcs_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'wcs_catalog_orderby' );
function wcs_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {

    $sortby['on_sale'] = 'Хямдралын хувиар';
    return $sortby;
}
```

Therefore, how can I sort/display both simple & variable products which are on discount/sale

Answer (score 3):

I know it is a bit old question, however, the solution I found might be helpful for someone.

After checking and trying different options, here is what worked for me. Results are amazing!

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'my_shop_product_query' );
function my_shop_product_query( $q ){
    if($q->query['orderby'] == 'on_sale'){ // this is very important condition to set otherwise it will affect your whole main query
        $sale_product_IDs = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();
        $q->set( 'post__in', $sale_product_IDs );
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'post__in' );
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great on newest version of woocommerce 5.8+, great answer thank you.

Comment: @Blu3 great to hear, happy it helped. Thanks

Comment: That means though any product without sale won't be shown which is fine it this use case I'd suppose but anyways needed to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one. It's Work for me in my scenario.

```
function cw_add_postmeta_ordering_args( $args_sort_cw ) {
  $cw_orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) :
        apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
  switch( $cw_orderby_value ) {
    case 'points_awarded':
      $args_sort_cw['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
      $args_sort_cw['order'] = 'desc';
      $args_sort_cw['meta_key'] = 'points';
      break;
       case 'location':
            $args_sort_cw['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
            $args_sort_cw['order'] = 'asc';
            $args_sort_cw['meta_key'] = 'location';
            break;
  }
  return $args_sort_cw;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'cw_add_postmeta_ordering_args' );
function cw_add_new_postmeta_orderby( $sortby ) {
   $sortby['location'] = __( 'Sort By Location', 'woocommerce' );
   $sortby['points_awarded'] = __( 'Sort By Sale Point', 'woocommerce' );
   return $sortby;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'cw_add_new_postmeta_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'cw_add_new_postmeta_orderby' );
```

FYR :- https://www.cloudways.com/blog/woocommerce-product-sort-and-display/

Comment: can u please look at my code and what's wrong with it? it is showing only the Sale/discount simple products, but not variable products.